# Half-loaded pages going blank when STOP is used in Firefox

Tags: firefox, webpage

I'm sure I'm not the only person this happens to...

Sometimes my browser is half-done loading a page and begins to choke on graphics or badly-written Javascript or some garbage ad crap, but the text I want to read is already on the screen, so I click STOP to free the browser from the clutches of the assy site and let me read my text in peace and... the page goes blank.

Firefox, it seems, has retracted the content that it was otherwise capable of displaying.

Why does this happen?

How can it be avoided, if at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's the normal Firefox behavior. I suppose when you hit stop he tries to render with the half-loaded resources but clears the screen as he can't do a partial rendering.