# Maintaining a webpage after pressing the Stop button

Tags: google-chrome, browser, webpage, browsing, navigation

Suppose I'm on a webpage and I decide to load a new webpage in the same tab, either by clicking refresh, clicking a link, or entering a URL.  And then if immediately I decide to change my mind and want to stay on the old page, that is precisely the kind of use case that the stop button is designed for.  Yet all the modern browsers in all the devices I've seen (both mobile and desktop) seem to have the stop function work in very undesirable way: it stops the new page from loading, but it replaces the old page with a blank white screen.

Now at a technical level, I think I understand what's going on: the browser displays whatever you've managed to download of the new page before you pressed stop, and so if you haven't downloaded anything yet you'll get nothing displayed.

But when I press stop, I typically don't want to see the new page, I want to still see the old page.  Is there a way, to get the old page to stay once you press stop?  Note that I don't want the old page to reload, I want it to simply remain.

What usually happens is that if you press stop while the old page is still visible, the old page is replaced by a blank screen immediately, while if the stop button is pressed after the new page starts being displayed, whatever parts of the new page had been displayed when you pressed stop remain.  So ideally, I want the stop button to work as follows: if the old page is still being displayed, let it remain; if the new page has started being displayed, let whatever has been displayed remain.  Is there any way to achieve this?

If it helps, I run Chrome on my Windows PC's (with various operating systems), and it would be nice if there were a command flag to do this.  Is there one?  Also, can I accomplish what I'm trying to do in iOS devices as well.

Comment: I havent seen this problem, nor can I reproduce it...

Comment: @Keltari Do you have an iPhone?  If so, can you see the problem there?  That's where I've encountered the problem lately, but I'm pretty sure that it's happened to me a lot on computers.

Comment: iPhones would be off topic here

Comment: @Keltari You weren't able to reproduce the issue on a computer even while pressing stop after clicking refresh?  That's where the problem is usually most annoying for me on a computer.  Like you try to refresh the page to see whether it's updated, but it's taking a while to load, so you click stop to try to prevent losing the current instance of the web page, but that causes the page to be replaced by a white screen.

Comment: @Keltari I can reproduce it in Chromium. Interestingly if I just leave it on that blank page eventually it tells me there is an unresponsive script.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/q/192890/670755

Comment: When you experience this problem, if you wait long enough do you get an unresponsive script? If so, [this bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=671043) seems relevant.

Comment: I just realised this question is 3 years old...

Comment: How about clicking back button/arrow? It can provide your previous (old) page without reloading.